# UIView created during initWithFrame:frame won't disappear after removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, subviews

This only occurs in iOS 4.3. There isn't a problem in iOS 5.

I've created a custom view. In initWithFrame:frame I'm creating several subviews and adding them to my view. Later, I try and remove those views:

```
for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The subviews are removed. If I print out the contents of self.subviews, they no longer exist. However, they won't disappear. They continue to be visible.

Any thoughts or ideas?

**Update**

It appears that in iOS 4.3, subviews are being added twice. I'm going to do further investigation.

Comment: Are you removing the views on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, I am. Later on in my code, I add and remove other subviews (using the same remove function), and everything works fine. But the initial views I add won't disappear.